# script php that return an image file

Tags: php, image, impressions

it's possibile to create a script in php that is used in img tag to show an image, for example:

```
<img src="http://domain.com/img.php?id=1" />
```

and when is called the script count the impressions (no problem here) and at the end **return the image in gif/jpg format**.

for now i use:

```
header( "Content-type: " . $type );
readfile( $img );
```

it work perfectly, but it don't return the  image file in gif/jpg format..

i need to change this script in way that when i type **domain.com/img.php?id=1** in the browser, the browser address should change to **domain.com/image.gif**

is this possibile?

Comment: There is no such mime type? Do you mean `image/jpeg` or `image/gif`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible
Just use htaccess rewrite code to hide the php address.
You may try this code on your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^*(.*)\.gif$ img.php?id=$1 [L]

Options All -Indexes

</IfModule>
```

It will change img.php?id=XXX into XXX.gif (not a real image file, just for masking the real address)

Comment: Isn't it the other way around it will change <whatever>.gif into img.php?id=<whatever>

Comment: @KristerAndersson maybe you can use your PHP code to call the <whatever>.gif